# Sort function C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stack

Problems with a sort function :void SortAge();
calling the function to print an employee name : void print(int d), I only recive the name of the first employee i had pushed into the Stack...
I don t have any sintax error
thank for time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
struct employee
{
string name;
int age;

};


class Stack
{
employee employeeList[1000];

int pos =-1;

public:

void push(employee e)
{
    pos++;
    employeeList[pos] = e;


}
employee pop(int n)
{
    employee e;
    if(n<= pos && pos >= 0 && n >=0)
    {

        e= employeeList[pos] ;
        for(int j =n; j < pos; j++ )
        {
            employeeList[pos] = employeeList[pos + 1];

        }

        pos--;
    }
    return e;
}

void print(int d)
{
    if(d > pos || d <0 || pos < 0)
    {
        cout<< "Error";

    }
    cout<<employeeList[d].name<<endl;
}

char menu()
{

    char choice;
    cout << "Press 1. to push an employee"<<endl;
    cout << "Press 2. to pop an employee"<<endl;
    cout << "Press 3. to show an employee"<<endl;
    cout << "Press 4. to sort the list by age"<<endl;
    cin>> choice;

    return choice;


}
void SortAge()
{
    int j;
    for(j = 0;j < pos ; j++)
    {
        if(employeeList[j].age >employeeList[j+1].age)
        {
            employee e;
            e = employeeList[j];
            employeeList[j+1] = employeeList[j];
            employeeList[j] = e;
            j = 0;
        } continue;
    }

}


 };

 int main()
 {
 Stack s;

int j;
for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
{
    char input = s.menu();
    switch(input)
    {
    case '1' :
        {
            employee e;
            cout<<"Enter Name :"<<endl;
            cin>>e.name;
            cout<<"Enter Age :"<<endl;
            cin>>e.age;
            s.push(e);
        }
        break;

        case '2' :
            {
                int n;
                cout<<"Enter at witch position you want to delete employee:"               <<endl;
                cin>>n;
                s.pop(n);
            }
            break;

        case '3' :
            {
                int n;
                cout<<"Enter the position of the employee you want to visualize"<<endl;
                cin>>n;
                s.print(n);
            }
            break;
        case '4' :
            {
                s.SortAge();
            }
            break;
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. (But then, I don't know what data you used.)

Comment: Your sort is broken - it does only one pass in what's almost a "bubble sort".  You should either google "bubble search" to find out how to fix it, or just use `std::sort`.

Comment: i forgot that i can t use precompiled function i m training for an univeristy test

Comment: with Ali Akber' s correction it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bubble sort. So change the sorting function-

```
    void SortAge()
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<=pos ;i++)
        {
            for(j = i+1 ; j <= pos ; j++)
            {
                if(employeeList[i].age >employeeList[j].age)
                {
                    employee e;
                    e = employeeList[j];
                    employeeList[j] = employeeList[i];
                    employeeList[i] = e;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

There is also an error in your `pop()` function :(

```
    employee pop(int n)
    {
        employee e;
        if(n<= pos && pos >= 0 && n >=0)
        {

            e= employeeList[pos] ;
            for(int j =n; j < pos; j++ )
            {
                employeeList[j] = employeeList[j + 1];
                // Changed
            }
            pos--;
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting algorithm is incorrect.

That aside, since you are using C++, why not just use [the built-in sorting function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

```
#include <algorithm>
...
void SortAge() {
    std::sort(employeeList, employeeList + pos + 1, [](employee a, employee b){return a.age < b.age});
}
```

Comment: @frasnian Should I do that even though the code in the question has `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Hostility is rather uncalled for. Most people that use it don't know any better because they haven't been taught otherwise or are students that haven't worked on real-world code.

Comment: @frasnian It could also be said, that when ever you see the horrible namespace syntax of C++, you should pull out your hair ;)

Comment: @hyde: please enlighten us - if you were on the Committee what namespace syntax would you have argued for, and why...? ;-P

Comment: @TonyD I don't know, it is a complex matter affecting many details of language design, and also something which predates any standardization committees I think... But just because it looks horrible to my eye doesn't mean it's easy to make better. But for what it's worth, C# syntax for namespaces looks much nicer to my eye.

Comment: @hyde: as an occasional user of C#, I can't say I even remember any differences of note... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Akash Jain's solution. Unless there is some restriction against using the built-in sort function , you should go for std::sort with a custom comparator (based on a predicate ) for your Employee class.

Also, why not use std::stack  . That way you can use the built-in pop() method to remove the topmost element.